# Show that an element of a compact metric space $M$ can be mapped to itself by continuous function $f : M → M$ with $d(f(x), x) < ε$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a (non-empty) compact metric space and $f:M \to M$ a continuous
map such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x \in M$ such that $d(f(x), x) < \epsilon$. Show that there exists $y \in M$ such that $f(y) = y$.

**Hint:** consider the map $g:M \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = d(f(x), x)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please add your own thoughts of how to approach the problem.

Comment: If you can show $g$ is continuous, then the extreme value theorem tells you it must attain a minimum. This minimum must be less than any $\varepsilon > 0$...

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I just take g equals 0, I am not sure how to use the compactness in the question.. That is why I put this question. Thanks for your attention

Comment: so I am not sure how to prove it by using all the conditions given by the question...

Comment: @Kono If you wish to notify someone that you've responded to their comment, then tag them with an @ followed by their user name.

Comment: When adding your own thoughts (which is essential to the post), please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let's define $g$ as in the hint, then your criterion says that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x \in M$ such that $g(x) < \epsilon$.

Can you prove that $\exists y \in M$ such that $g(y) = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I show g is continuous? Could you please give me a further hint?

Answer (score 2):

$g$ is continuous. Since the domain is compact it attains its minimum value, say $m$. Let $m=g(x_0)=f(f(x_0),x_0)$. If $m=0$ we are done since $f(x_0)=x_0$ in this case.   Otherwise choose a positive number  $\epsilon <m$. Let $x$ be as in the hypotheis. Then $m \leq d(f(x),x)<\epsilon$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you sir.I can understand your opinion but why g is continuous?

Comment: Use the fact that $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')| \leq d(x,x')+d(y,y')$. @Kono